# Logback -after reload logback-spring file not printing proper application logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to changes max history dynamically, for that when I started the service it will print normally after service start I added command line runner to create config/logback.include.xml file after that reloading the log back file, in this case, its not printing proper console,
and the same code working fine when restart the spring application.
Can anyone please help me?
Thank you.

14:44:10,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [ch.qos.logback.core.property.FileExistsPropertyDefiner]
14:44:10,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [propExists] from the object stack
14:44:10,070 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@389087a2 - Adding [file:/Users/p3/march_01/archon-notification-channel/config/logback-included.xml] to configuration watch list.
14:44:10,074 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@2:127 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
14:44:10,074 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:104 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
14:44:10,075 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:99 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
14:44:10,075 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:118 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
14:44:10,075 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:110 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
14:44:10,075 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
14:44:10,075 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
14:44:10,075 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
14:44:10,079 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
14:44:10,079 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [ROLLING]
14:44:10,079 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
14:44:10,083 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@442989314 - setting totalSizeCap to 10 MB
14:44:10,083 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@442989314 - No compression will be used
14:44:10,084 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@442989314 - Will use the pattern ./notification-channel/notification-channel_1_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}*%i.log for the active file
14:44:10,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@50843fd4 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH' from file name pattern './notification-channel/notification-channel_1*%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}_%i.log'.
14:44:10,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@50843fd4 - Roll-over at the top of every hour.
14:44:10,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@50843fd4 - Setting initial period to Wed Mar 03 14:44:10 IST 2021
14:44:10,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@50843fd4 - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
14:44:10,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@50843fd4 - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
14:44:10,085 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@442989314 - Cleaning on start up
14:44:10,086 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
14:44:10,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLING] - Active log file name: ./notification-channel/notification-channel_1_2021-03-03_14_0.log
14:44:10,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLING] - File property is set to [null]
14:44:10,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
14:44:10,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ROLLING] to Logger[ROOT]
14:44:10,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
14:44:10,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
14:44:10,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@15e2d450 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
14:44:10,113 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Removed  0 Bytes of files

```
 private void reloadLogger() {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logback-spring.xml");
        try {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
            configurator.doConfigure(url);
            loggerContext.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHandler.exception(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }

logback-spring.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <define name="propExists" class="ch.qos.logback.core.property.FileExistsPropertyDefiner">
        <path>config/logback-included.xml</path>
    </define>
    <if condition="${propExists}">
        <then>
            <include file="config/logback-included.xml"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <springProperty defaultValue="info" name="log_level" scope="context" source="customlog.level"/>
            <springProperty defaultValue="." name="log_path" scope="context" source="customlog.path"/>
            <springProperty defaultValue="1" name="instance_id" scope="context" source="spring.application.instance_id"/>
            <springProperty defaultValue="archon-audit-service" name="app_name" scope="context" source="spring.application.name"/>
            <springProperty defaultValue="LOGGER_STD" name="profile" scope="context" source="customlog.profile"/>
            <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M %line - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
            <if condition="(&quot;${profile}&quot;).contains(&quot;LOGGER_STD_FILE&quot;)">
                <then>
                    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="ROLLING">
                        <encoder>
                            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M %line - %msg%n</pattern>
                        </encoder>
                        <if condition="property(&quot;${log_path}&quot;).contains(&quot;.&quot;)">
                            <then>
                                <file/>
                            </then>
                            <else>
                                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                                    <fileNamePattern>${log_path}/${app_name}/${app_name}_${instance_id}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                                        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
                                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                                    <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
                                    <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
                                    <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
                                </rollingPolicy>
                            </else>
                        </if>
                    </appender>
                    <root additivity="false" level="${log_level}">
                        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
                        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
                    </root>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <root additivity="false" level="${log_level}">
                        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
                    </root>
                </else>
            </if>
        </else>
    </if>
</configuration>


logback-include.xml file (config/logback-include.xml)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><included>
        <springProperty defaultValue="notification-channel" name="app_name" scope="context" source="spring.application.name"/>
        <springProperty defaultValue="info" name="log_level" scope="context" source="customlog.level"/>
        <springProperty defaultValue="." name="log_path" scope="context" source="customlog.path"/>
        <springProperty defaultValue="1" name="instance_id" scope="context" source="spring.application.instance_id"/>
        <springProperty defaultValue="LOGGER_STD" name="profile" scope="context" source="customlog.profile"/>
                         <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
                             <encoder>
                                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M %line - %msg%n</pattern>
                             </encoder>
                         </appender>
                         <if condition="(&quot;${profile}&quot;).contains(&quot;LOGGER_STD_FILE&quot;)">
                                 <then>
                                      <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="ROLLING">
                                                    <encoder>
                                                         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M %line - %msg%n</pattern>
                                                    </encoder>
                                                    <if condition="property(&quot;${log_path}&quot;).contains(&quot;.&quot;)">
                                                        <then>
                                                             <file/>
                                                        </then>
                                                        <else>
                                                            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                                                             <fileNamePattern>${log_path}/${app_name}/${app_name}_${instance_id}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                                                             <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                                                                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
                                                             </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                                                             <maxHistory>150</maxHistory>
                                                             <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
                                                             <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
                                                             </rollingPolicy>
                                                        </else>
                                                    </if>
                                               </appender>
                                               <root additivity="false" level="${log_level}">
                                                      <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
                                                      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
                                               </root>
                                 </then>
                                 <else>
                                     <root additivity="false" level="${log_level}">
                                          <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
                                     </root>
                                 </else>
                         </if>
</included>
```